# How do I fade a whole scene?

Tags: 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

I have a scene that I want to fade to complete transparency on the outside. The blue object in the picture (continues in the larger red/white object) should gradually no longer be visible from the beginning of the red towards the white. If possible, the whole thing should also work in eevee.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried with boolean modifier?

Comment: Do you want it to disappear as a gradient or as a solid line?

Comment: Do you want everything to fade out to transparency as a flat image (use compositor) or individually (change materials)? Think of a human being, disappearing - in movies that's typically *"flat"*, but in reality if you were becoming transparent, you would clearly see the muscles and bones in half of the transition (50% opacity skin and 50% opacity muscles underneath makes you see muscles as if they had 25% opacity).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using shader node too(Procedurally)
Follow this node group:

[image]

Value node gives the fade effect. Play with the values to get the desired effect.

Result:

[image]

P.S. Make sure you join both the objects

P.P.S If you wanna change the axis on which the fading occurs, change the value of last greater than node with Y or Z output from separate XYZ node

BLEND FILE: https://pasteall.org/blend/e1e9617c0bed4c18b372d759462ffb94

Comment: Also, if you are in evee u need to set blend mode to alpha clip.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is the boolean modifier, like Emir proposed:

1. Join both objects
2. Add a box which is big enough that the whole object fits in it
3. add boolean modifier to your object with target to object created in 2 -> intersect
4. animate the object you created in 2

If you need further explanation, let me know.

If you need video tutorial, let me know.

result:

https://youtu.be/ZKb4sLJVu34

another possibility: (this is what you normally call fade out)

just extend your materials like this:

[image]

and animate the Fac value in the mix shader from 0 to 1.

make sure, your blend mode is set to alpha blend.

[image]

result:

Comment: ...but i am pretty sure, Robin Betts can do this procedurally, moonboots much cooler and batFinger in python in just 45 secs. :D

Comment: I would like but I don't even understand the question  :p

Comment: Worst lie ever 

Comment: First of all, thank you for the quick answer. I have added a second picture. This one should show what I actually mean, a kind of fog look. I'm thinking of the FOV in Minecraft. That the objects are not suddenly no longer visible, but gradually. The whole thing should not be animated, but happen in a single frame.

Comment: @Chris, you see, doesn't seem obvious

Comment: @dnlpck, maybe show a storyboard (several images) to make it more clear?

Comment: It's difficult when I don't have clear words for this effect. In a tutorial I saw months ago, this was suggested among other things. If I remember correctly, vertex groups and weight paint were used to mark the area that should gradually fade.

Comment: @moonboots you are Right, sorry!